# Complex SQL Query Help

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Given a pretty standard set of related tables like Customers, Invoices and Line Items.  I need to make a query like "Select all customers that have invoices that have 5 line items or more"  or "Select all customers that have more than 2 invoices" or lastly "Select all customers that have line items totaling more than $100"

I'm doing this the hard way now (walking through all the records manually) and I know it's the most inefficient way but I don't know enough SQL to construct these queries. I'm using PHP5, MySQL and CakePHP 1.25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by joining them all together:

```
select c.id
from customers c
left join invoices i on i.customer_id = c.id
left join lineitems li on li.invoice_id = i.id
group by c.id
```

To filter customers with more than 5 line items or more, add:

```
having count(li.id) >= 5
```

Filtering customers with two or more invoices is trickier, since we're joining the lineitems table.  There may be multiple rows per invoice.  So to count only unique invoices, we have to add `distinct` to the count, like:

```
having count(distinct i.id) >= 2
```

To filter customers with more than $100 in items, add:

```
having sum(li.cost) > 100
```

You can use math inside the `sum`, in case you're storing separate line item counts and prices:

```
having sum(li.itemcount * li.itemcost) > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first two you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*)>4` and for the last one you can use `SUM(field)`.

If you want SQL then please show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Say you had:

`customers.id`

`line_items.user_id`

`line_items.numItems`

Query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM customers
JOIN line_items
ON line_items.user_id WHERE line_items.numItems > 5
```

Your `WHERE` clause will change depending on what you wanted to return.

Haven't worked with [SQL Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) in a while, but I think it's something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some help with the second one that should get you going:

```
   SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS num_invoices
     FROM invoices
 GROUP BY customer_id 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```